# Updating pyplot graph in real time

Tags: python, matplotlib, time

I'm trying to plot a 2D grid of data and map them to colors. Then I want to update the values and have the graph update with the new values. Currently the graph only shows the final result, not all the middle phases the graph should go through.

MY CODE::

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.animation as animation



thing=0
NUM_COL=10
NUM_ROW=10

zvals=np.full((NUM_ROW,NUM_COL),-5.0)

def update_graph(zvals):
    zvals+=1
    pyplot.clf()
    img = pyplot.imshow(zvals,interpolation='nearest',
                    cmap = cmap,norm=norm)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyplot.draw()

# make a color map of fixed colors
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['blue','black','red'])
bounds=[-6,-2,2,6]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# tell imshow about color map so that only set colors are used

img = pyplot.imshow(zvals,interpolation='nearest',
                    cmap = cmap,norm=norm)

# make a color bar
pyplot.colorbar(img,cmap=cmap,norm=norm,boundaries=bounds,ticks=[-5,0,5])



pyplot.draw()

for i in range(5):
    update_graph(zvals)

pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`pyplot` does not generally show anything until `pyplot.show()` is called, unless `matplotlib` runs in 'interactive' mode. The interactive mode is entered by calling `pyplot.ion()` and can exited again by calling `pyplot.ioff()`.

Thus it should be possible for you to see all your updates by calling `pyplot.ion()` somewhere before doing anything you want to be directly updated and then end your program with `pyplot.ioff()` to get back to the standard `pyplot` way when done.

However, it may not look very smooth, depending on your system and what updates you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this a *good* answer or not, I have only used updating plots once before. But this is a way to achieve what you want.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

NUM_COL = 10
NUM_ROW = 10

zvals = np.full((NUM_ROW,NUM_COL),-5.0)
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['blue','black','red'])
bounds = [-6,-2,2,6]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

fig = plt.figure() # Create the figure
img = plt.imshow(zvals,interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap,norm=norm) # display the first image
plt.colorbar(img,cmap=cmap,norm=norm,boundaries=bounds,ticks=[-5,0,5]) # create your colour bar

# If we dont have this, then animation.FuncAnimation will call update_graph upon initialization
def init():
    pass

# animation.FuncAnimation will use this function to update the plot. This is where we update what we want displayed
def update_graph(frame):
    global zvals # zvals is a global variable
    zvals+=1 
    img.set_data(zvals) # This sets the data to the new, updated values
    print("Frame Update {}".format(frame)) # this is for debugging to help you see whats going on
    return img

# This is what will run the animations
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, init_func = init,
                                                  interval  = 1000, # update every 1000ms
                                                  frames  = 8, # Update 8 times
                                                  repeat=False) # After 8 times, don't repeat the animation
plt.show() # show our plot
```